# Microsoft SCCM, Reporting is not running on local Computer

Tags: sccm

We updated our Microsoft SCCM to Version 1806.

Reporting is running, but I cannot see them in SCCM.

Last Saturday, based on the failed Certificate for the Reporting server in SCCM, I can not open up my Reports.

I can go over my SCCM under Reporting and it does shows me 2 Links for the Reporting Server.

I can open those two Links but it shows me on the browser that the Certificates expired, last Saturday, October the 13th.

I can work with those 2 Links in Reporting, but I need to know howto replace that Certificate for the use in SCCM.

Update: I created a new Certificate on my main Microsoft SCCM Server. I updated my IIS for HTTPS with the new Certification for the Config Web Server Certificate and restarted the Service. Now I can see the Reporting in the Configuration Manager Console. But I can't see the Reporting Service on my local installed Configuration Manager Console, anything else in the SCCM Console is working.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question seems to be offtopic, as Stackoverflow is about programming. See also the [sccm tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sccm/info): *You should also consider if your question is suitable for StackOverflow. Since StackOverflow mainly caters to developers, good candidates for questions include: Questions regarding the development of extensions to the SCCM console Questions involving programmatic/scripted access to data within SCCM More general questions regarding SCCM (e.g. managing applications through the SCCM console) may be answered more easily on ServerFault.*

Comment: On a side note, please don't post updates and additional information as comments. Edit the question instead. (I have added your update into the question already, but I cannot remove your comment.)